# SQL How to extract Middle Characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that looks like this.  I need to extract after the third '/', or to pull out the section called 'Reports' from this string.

/WM/Operational/Reports/ReportName

**I have tried the following:**

This gives me the last part or the ReportName

```
= RIGHT(col,charindex('/',reverse(col),1)-1)
```

this removes the leading characters after the 3rd '/' character  *(number of characters are different than above string to hide details)*

```
= RIGHT(col, LEN(col) - 31)
```

How do I combine this together to remove the first part after the 3rd '/' and remove the reportname?

Comment: Include example input and output so that anything created can also be tested. That will also help us determine what parts of the string are static (never changing).

Comment: Is the format of your string always exactly 4 elements with a leading slash? Or do you have varying numbers of elements and the slash may or may not be there?

Comment: always exactly 4 elements with a leading slash

Comment: Sorry, there are some with 5 elements with a leading slash

Comment: Don't you think it would be easier to add some sample data and desired reports ?

Comment: The data is highly sensitive.  I'm not able to add sample data

Comment: That is too funny.   We can deal with patterns

Comment: Thanks John.  Please edit the link posted above.  This link is my question.

Comment: Sorry.  Bad copy/paste  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=42a1f9d203a9e5083a88dc9472435c6c

Comment: John, nice work.  This is excellent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the format of your example string has no more than 4 parts you could make use of `parsename` here:

```
declare @col varchar(50) = '/WM/Operational/Reports/ReportName';

select ParseName(Replace(stuff(@col, 1, 1, ''), '/', '.'), 2);
```

Comment: I'm getting some NULLS.  The NULLs are on some with 5 elements with a leading slash and where the report name begins with a number.

Comment: It's a shame you didn't have better sample data, unfortunately `Parsename` only works with up to 4 parts as it's intented to extract parts from fully qualified names. You could always still use it and strip off the first element and `/` to leave 4.